# Loading HTML file based on @mediascreen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Happy Monday to everyone.

I was hoping that someone could help me with an issue I am having. Before I made the changes today, I had one animation from Google Web Designer running on the page - however I had to create multiple animations to accommodate different screen sizes (unfortunately, GWD does not allow for scalable animations yet).

So I created a number of additional animations in GWD and they are published as HTML files. Previously i was able to load the one html file without issues, but now that I have 4 different html files, I am trying to get each respective file to load depending on a @media screen css function.

Problem is, the @media queries are successfully stopping the div from loading where I specifying, however the page is only loading the last html file I have listed below. Any thoughts?

I am using the following to load the 4 html files (the 'user agent' stylesheet loads the inner script as none for the first 3:

```
<div id="animation_wrapper">
    <div id="frameContainer">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            onload = function () {
                var el = document.getElementById("frameContainer")
                el.innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation.html\"></iframe>"
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    <div id="frameContainer_medium">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            onload = function () {
                var el = document.getElementById("frameContainer_medium")
                el.innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_medium.html\"> </iframe>"
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    <div id="frameContainer_small">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            onload = function () {
                var el = document.getElementById("frameContainer_small")
                el.innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_small.html\">    </iframe>"
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    <div id="frameContainer_very_small">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            onload = function () {
                var el = document.getElementById("frameContainer_very_small")
                el.innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_very_small.html\">    </iframe>"
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1367px) {
    /* Large Animation */
    #animation_wrapper {
        padding-top: 10%;
    }
    div #frameContainer {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        width: 70%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 0;
    }
    div #frameContainer iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 15%;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    div #frameContainer_medium {
        display: none;
    }
    div #frameContainer_small {
        display: none;
    }
    div #frameContainer_very_small {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1366px) {
    /* Medium Animation */
    div #frameContainer {
        display: none;
    }
    div #frameContainer_medium {
        display: block;
    }
    div #frameContainer_small {
        display: none;
    }
    div #frameContainer_very_small {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 450px) and (max-width: 899px) {
    /* Small Animation */
    div #frameContainer {
        display: none;
    }
    div #frameContainer_medium {
        display: none;
    }
    div #frameContainer_small {
        display: block;
    }
    div #frameContainer_very_small {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 227px) and (max-width: 449px) {
    /* Very Small Animation */
    div #frameContainer {
        display: none;
    }
    div #frameContainer_medium {
        display: none;
    }
    div #frameContainer_small {
        display: none;
    }
    div #frameContainer_very_small {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only last `onload` assignment will work here, as this is redefining itself in each block.

Folllowing code should work:

```
<div id="animation_wrapper">                   
<div id="frameContainer">
<script type="text/javascript">
onload=function(){
var el1=document.getElementById("frameContainer")
el1.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation.html\"></iframe>"

var el2=document.getElementById("frameContainer_medium")
el2.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_medium.html\"> </iframe>"

var el3=document.getElementById("frameContainer_small")
el3.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_small.html\">    </iframe>"

var el4=document.getElementById("frameContainer_very_small")
el4.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://energyamplified.co.za/animation_very_small.html\">    </iframe>"

}
</script>
</div>
<div id="frameContainer_medium">
</div>
<div id="frameContainer_small">
</div>
<div id="frameContainer_very_small">
</div>
</div>
```